# Is there a single page that describes all the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes find it difficult to decide which is the appropriate site to ask a question.  For example, I have a question today about choosing a web platform for a new UNIX server we are purchasing.  Since it's not a "programming" question exactly, it's probably off-topic for Stack Overflow, but I cannot decide where it should be asked.  Possibilities include **SuperUser**, **UNIX**, and **WebMasters**.

I know I can visit each site and read the "About" page, but is there a page somewhere that describes the goals of all the Stack sites, like a "Table of Contents"?

I do realize that my question about a web platform might not be appropriate for any of the sites (since in some ways I'm asking for advice).  I'll check the rules first.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites?

Comment: @RobW That would be good if it displayed a "mission statement" for each site.  The descriptions are a bit sparse.

Comment: Your hypothetical question sounds like a shopping recommendation question, so the answer to "which SE site should I use" is easy: none of them.

Comment: @Wooble I don't think that's relevant to my question here.  If I can't find a site that allows questions like mine, I won't ask.  **This** question is asking if a single document exists that describes all the sites, just to save a little time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the table view at https://stackexchange.com/sites is descriptive enough. Putting all of the about pages on it would be an overkill.

You can at least choose a couple that look fitting and then check them in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, but those descriptions are not useful (to me); they mostly are of the form **"Foo- A Q&A site for users of Foo"**.  The real estate showing all those stats would be better used to show a descriptive paragraph.